# Generate GridView without pageload

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview

Currently, I am populating a grid view in ASP.NET by making calls to an API and using the response as the values.

This is using an `.aspx` page however I wish to populate the grid view without doing a postback.

**Aspx**

```
<div class="scroll" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto" 
     id="gridDiv" runat="server" visible="false">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView" runat="server">
        <Columns>
            //columns
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

**C#**

```
public void populateGrid()
{        
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    // add values to dt 

    GridView.DataSource = dt;
    GridView.DataBind();
}
```

Is there a way, using Javascript, that I could call the API to retrieve the values and populate the grid view without doing a post back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gridview is a server control, so it needs all the server-side magic to make it work.  If you want to update the grid client-side, you'll need to go with a different solution.  One that is not an asp.net server control.

Answer (score 1):

The `GridView` control you are speaking of is an ASP.NET server control, therefore it requires the server-side WebForms engine to parse the control and generate HTML output; so the short answer is no you cannot use the `<asp:GridView>` markup and then have the client-side render the actual grid view output.

There are, however, client-side template solutions to building a JavaScript-based grid view-like control, read [Ajax Enabled Gridview using JavaScript in ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33401/Ajax-Enabled-Gridview-using-JavaScript-in-ASP-NET). This implementation uses an ASP.NET HTTP Handler to retrieve the data from the server and then JavaScript functions to build up the HTML output rendered to the page. This could easily be modified to use jQuery to make AJAX calls to HTTP Handlers (.ashx), ASP.NET AJAX Page Methods, web services, ASP.NET Web API, WCF services or event REST endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

1. Short & quick: `Use ASP.NET UpdatePanel`
2. Use jQuery with any client side grid plugin [JQGrid Demos](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html#)
3. Use jQuery to manipulate your gridview control (Requires a whole lot of work!) [Bind Dataset to Gridview using jQuery](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Bind-Dataset-to-ASPNet-GridView-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx)

I am more in favour or 1 and 2 since you are using webforms.